# Direct authentication of instagram user without showing the login page or any authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instagram

I am making an instagram application using rails. Is it possible
to save some kind of 'token' or 'id' in my database that can be used
to automatically authenticate the user and allow the application to
access the user's profile data, images,etc,etc without asking the user
to enter the login details/authentication again and again. If it is possible please
tell me how it can be done.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Please tell me how you implement direct authorization? I want to do the same with PHP.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to get a token. Take a look at the documentation concerning authentication, it's pretty comprehensive.

http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Comment: It is given that the token expires in some time. Is it possible to have a permanent token?

Comment: Not at the moment, extracted from the page above: "Note that we do not include an expiry time. Our access_tokens **have no explicit expiry**, though your app should handle the case that either the user revokes access or we expire the token after some period of time. In this case, your response's meta will contain an "error_type=OAuthAccessTokenError". In other words: **do do not assume your access_token is valid forever**."

Comment: @JorgeNúñez Please tell me how can I implement the same with PHP.

Comment: Link is dead at the moment- See updated http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/